# How to make group of widgets in canvas responsible

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

First of all, I'm sorry for my English and lack of knowledge about tkinter. I have been trying to fix this this whole week, unsuccessfully.

So I am making my first GUI app and I have chosen tkinter to do this job. Right now I am completing my program's feature that shows all records from database (SQLite) and I am feeding these records into labels. The List is already scrollable and stuff, but my problem is that items inside frame in canvas are not responsive so they kinda underflow my frame.

I have already tried experimenting with weights, but nothing has changed the situation for better. I have also tried to reconfigure the frame to width of canvas, but it hasn't changed so I suppose that the canvas by itself "overflows" the root window. So I have tried giving it fixed width of parent by Configure but that just made thing worse.

```py
class List(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)

        createBackground(self)

        def populate(object, list): # function to feed text from database to the grid
            iterate = 0
            for row in list:

                count = 0

                for element in row:

                    tk.Label(object, text=element,borderwidth=1, relief="solid", bg="yellow", fg="black", width=20).grid(row=iterate,column=count,sticky="NWES",ipady=8)

                    count += 1


                iterate +=+ 1


        def onFrameConfigure(event):
            self.canvas.configure(scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox("all"))

        self.basic_frame = tk.Frame(self, bg="white")
        self.basic_frame.grid(row=1,column=1, padx=30, pady=30, sticky="NWES")

        # shanenigens with tkinter so I could scroll down
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self.basic_frame, background="red", borderwidth=0)
        self.frame = tk.Frame(self.canvas, background="blue")
        self.scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(self.basic_frame, orient=tk.VERTICAL, bg="white")
        self.scrollbar.config(command=self.canvas.yview)
        self.canvas.config(yscrollcommand=self.scrollbar.set, scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox(tk.ALL))

        self.canvas.grid(row=1,column=0, columnspan=9, sticky="NWES")
        self.scrollbar.grid(row=0,column=10, rowspan=2,sticky="NWES")

        self.grid_rowconfigure(1,weight=1)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(1,weight=1)
        self.basic_frame.grid_rowconfigure(1,weight=1)

        self.frame.grid_rowconfigure(1,weight=1)
        self.frame.grid_columnconfigure(1,weight=1)



        for x in range(9): # setting grid weights
            self.basic_frame.grid_columnconfigure(x,weight=1)
            self.canvas.grid_columnconfigure(x,weight=1)

        label_array = ["Name","Author","Pages","Genre","ISBN","Language","Read","Owned","Added"] # making labels in List

        for element in label_array:
            label_name = tk.Label(self.basic_frame, text=element, bg="#0AB300",fg="black",borderwidth=1, relief="solid",width=20)
            label_name.grid(row=0, column=label_array.index(element),sticky="NWES",ipady=8)


        self.canvas.create_window((0,0), window=self.frame,anchor="nw",tags="feed_list")


        self.frame.bind("<Configure>", onFrameConfigure)

        books_list = select_all() # getting every element from database
        populate(self.frame, books_list)
```

Here is a link for screenshot:
https://ctrlv.cz/qX7N

Comment: You are using different `Frame`s, (`.basic_frame`, `.frame`), for **Header** and **Data**, therefore they can not sync. You have two options: **1.** Use only **one** `Frame`. **2.** Use **fixed** `width` for **every** celll and forbid `propagation`.

Comment: I am gonna try both approaches and see the results, but i was aware about the first one. It was made on purpose so that user can still see the Header when he is scrolling through Data. And the second approach wont be responsible. But even though thanks and tomorrow I will post result.

Comment: Result of 1. approach has  confirmed that the problem is with canvas frame itself (https://ctrlv.cz/BR8a). Just to know there is one more column that is not shown because the non existing responsibility.

Comment: Can you explain the problem you are having again? I tried to run your code with minimal data and it seemed to work just fine.

Comment: @MichalVaňata: **3.** Solution, use a outer `Frame` for every column. Inside this outer `Frame` place your `.basic_frame`, `.frame`. The outer `Frame` have to be **fixed** `width` so the inner `Frame`s `width` are bounded.

Comment: @HenryYik I have a frame with many labels. Because there are many labels (as many as user adds), I have made the labels scrollable with canvas and scrollbar. I wanted to have on row of fixed HEADER labels (Name, Author, etc...) and records from DATABASE under it. To make the HEADER fixed I have put it in the parent frame with canvas and scrollbar widget. The Problem is that widgets inside canvas widget are not responsive that means that they have fixed size and therefore are not displayed if you don't have enough big monitor.

Comment: @stovfl Sorry for my ignoration but I dont simply dont understand what are you trying to say. Could you maybe elaborate your answer a little bit?

Comment: PS: Here is link to my Github repo with this programm so you may replicate the problem if you want: https://github.com/Daybringer/meklebi

Comment: @MichalVaňata: See my image [Issue - OuterFrame](https://github.com/Daybringer/meklebi/issues/2)

Comment: is there any specific reason you are trying to do this by griding labels instead of using the `Treeview` widget? It would be a lot easier.

Comment: @HenryYik I haven't known about tkinter.ttk. Thank you for this tip.